# QProcess disable stdout redirection

Tags: qt

I want to start a process from a QT app and catch its termination event. Its done with the method QProcess::start(). But unlike in startDetached(), the standard output of the process is redirected to a buffer. I don't want that.
I can't find how to disable it. An ugly workaround is to call setStandardOutputFile("/dev/stdout")

test.h

```
#ifndef MY_TEST_H
#define MY_TEST_H

#include <QCoreApplication>

class MyApp : public QCoreApplication {
  Q_OBJECT  
  private Q_SLOTS:
    void subprocessStarted();
    void subprocessFinished(int);
  public:
    MyApp( int & argc, char ** argv );
};

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

#include <QProcess>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ENTRY printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

MyApp::MyApp( int & argc, char ** argv ) : QCoreApplication(argc, argv) {
  ENTRY;

  QProcess *process = new QProcess();
  //process->setStandardOutputFile("/dev/stdout");
  process->start("/bin/echo aaa");
  bool b;
  b = connect(process, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(subprocessStarted()));
  printf("connect started %d\n", b);
  b = connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), SLOT(subprocessFinished(int)));
  printf("connect finished %d\n", b);
}
void MyApp::subprocessStarted() {
  ENTRY;
}
void MyApp::subprocessFinished(int ret) {
  ENTRY;
  printf("%d\n", ret);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ENTRY;
  MyApp a(argc, argv);
  return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [QProcess::closeReadChannel(ProcessChannel channel)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#closeReadChannel) work for you?

> Closes the read channel channel. After calling this function, QProcess
>   will no longer receive data on the channel. Any data that has already
>   been received is still available for reading. Call this function to
>   save memory, if you are not interested in the output of the process.

Like this-

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->start("/bin/echo aaa");
process->closeReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
process->closeReadChannel(QProcess::StandardError);
```